# In Vu Gen Recorde Script username n password are saved in web_add_cookie() function

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

Using socket level as port, in HP Load Runner Vu Gen the recorded scrit contains usernm and password of application in cookie i.e is web_add_cookie() function, need them recorded in other than cookie plz suggest

Protocol Used : Web(HTTP/HTML)
Port Mapping as Socket Level

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the application puts information into a cookie, the information is in a cookie.  You cannot (generally) change the way an application behaves by virtue of your testing.

What you can do, however, is correlate the credentials with a web_reg_save_param_ex call and do with them what you need to do.